# Getting the opposite boolean output of anonymous functions [SML]

Tags: sml

Part of a solution, I'm trying to figure a way in order to convert the value of a boolean anonymous function to its opposite. for example I have function `f` which is as following: `fn x => x > 8`. I would like some operator like `not` which will convert the output to be the opposite, so the anonymous will actually calculate `fn x => x <= 8`. Something like as following:

```
fun foo f x = not f x;
```

But it won't work because `not` works only on boolean values. I know that I can do it as following:

```
fun foo f x = if f x then false else true;
```

But, I want to somehow do it in one line without any `ifs`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

There is already `not` which can be composed with a predicate, e.g. like:

```
val isntSpace = not o Char.isSpace
```

In OCaml's [Base library](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/base/Base/) there is a function [`Fn.non`](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/base/Base/Fn/#val-non) that does this:

```
fun non f x = not (f x)
```

It seems that you were only a set of parentheses away from this.

This would let you write:

```
val isntSpace = non Char.isSpace
```

Comment: In SML it is easy to be "only a set of parentheses away" from working code (even if you have been programming in the language for a while).